# Call R in Java for ARIMA

Tags: java, r, arima, jri

I try to call R in JAVA for ARIMA function. The first example runs arima(). It works well.

```
Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"},false,null);
System.out.println("  *BEGIN*  ");
rengine.eval("library(forecast)");
double[] trainingData = = {10930,10318,10595,10972,7706,6756,9092,10551,9722,10913,11151,8186,6422,
            + 6337,11649,11652,10310,12043,7937,6476,9662,9570,9981,9331,9449,6773,6304,9355,10477,
            + 10148,10395,11261,8713,7299,10424,10795,11069,11602,11427,9095,7707,10767,12136,12812,
            + 12006,12528,10329,7818,11719,11683,12603,11495,13670,11337,10232,13261,13230,15535,
            + 16837,19598,14823,11622,19391,18177,19994,14723,15694,13248,9543,12872,13101,15053,
            + 12619,13749,10228,9725,14729,12518,14564,15085,14722,11999,9390,13481,14795,15845,
            + 15271,14686,11054,10395,14775,14618,16029,15231,14246,12095,10473,15323,15381,14947};
rengine.assign("value", trainingData);
rengine.eval("traindatats<-ts(value)");
rengine.eval("loopMinLag<-0");
rengine.eval("loopMaxLag<-8");
rengine.eval("best.order <- c(loopMinLag, 1, loopMinLag)");
rengine.eval("best.aic = Inf");
rengine.eval("for(P in loopMinLag:loopMaxLag) { for(Q in loopMinLag:loopMaxLag) { myModel <- arima(traindatats, order=c(P,1,Q), method='ML'); fit.aic <- myModel$aic;  if(fit.aic < best.aic) { best.order <- c(P, 1, Q);  best.aic <- fit.aic; }  } }");
rengine.eval("model <- list()");
rengine.eval("model$P <- best.order[1]");
rengine.eval("model$D <- 1");
rengine.eval("model$Q <- best.order[3]");
rengine.eval("ar<-arima(traindatats,order=c(model$P,model$D,model$Q))");
rengine.eval("f<-predict(ar,n.ahead=7)");
System.out.println("  *RESULT*  ");
double forecast[] = new double[7];
for (int i = 0,j=1; i < 7; i++,j++) {
          forecast[i] = rengine.eval("f$pred[" + j + "]").asDouble();
          System.out.print(" "+forecast[i]);
      }
System.out.println("\r\n  *DONE* ");
```

The result is [the prediction values for the next 7 numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULqMJ.jpg). There is no any problem for arima() running in JAVA. The second example runs auto.arima(). 
However, it doesn't work. Does anyone know why it can't work?

```
Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"},false,null);
System.out.println("  *BEGIN*  ");
rengine.eval("library(forecast)");
double[] trainingData =  {10930,10318,10595,10972,7706,6756,9092,10551,9722,10913,11151,8186,6422,
            + 6337,11649,11652,10310,12043,7937,6476,9662,9570,9981,9331,9449,6773,6304,9355,10477,
            + 10148,10395,11261,8713,7299,10424,10795,11069,11602,11427,9095,7707,10767,12136,12812,
            + 12006,12528,10329,7818,11719,11683,12603,11495,13670,11337,10232,13261,13230,15535,
            + 16837,19598,14823,11622,19391,18177,19994,14723,15694,13248,9543,12872,13101,15053,
            + 12619,13749,10228,9725,14729,12518,14564,15085,14722,11999,9390,13481,14795,15845,
            + 15271,14686,11054,10395,14775,14618,16029,15231,14246,12095,10473,15323,15381,14947};
Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"},false,null);
System.out.println("  *BEGIN*  ");
rengine.assign("value", trainingData);
rengine.eval("traindatats<-ts(value)");
rengine.eval("ar<-auto.arima(traindatats)");
rengine.eval("f<-predict(ar,n.ahead=" + 7 + ")");
double forecast[] = new double[7];
for (int i = 0,j=1; i < forcastSize; i++,j++) {
          forecast[i] = rengine.eval("f$pred[" + j + "]").asDouble();
          System.out.print(" "+forecast[i]);
}
System.out.println("  *DONE*  ");
```

The error message is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" for the line `forecast[i] = rengine.eval("f$pred[" + j + "]").asDouble();`

PS. Both of examples for arima() and auto.arima() can run in R correctly. The corresponding R code for auto.arima() can run in R correctly, as shown in [auto.arima R example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpqfL.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
rengine.eval("f$pred[" + j + "]").asDouble();
```

`rengine.eval("f$pred[" + j + "]")` this one is null.

According to: http://www.rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html#eval(java.lang.String)

> eval
>
> public REXP eval(java.lang.String s)
>
> ```
> Parses and evaluates an R expression and returns the result. Has the same effect as calling eval(s, true).
>
> Parameters:
>
>     s - expression (as string) to parse and evaluate
> Returns:
>     resulting expression or null if something wnet wrong
> ```

It looks, like something goes wrong on R side.

Well, maybe you have some sort of issues with libraries, etc.

If I install forecast

```
install.packages('forecast')
```

inside R, and I call the code like this:

```
javac -cp /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/jri/JRI.jar SimpleR.java
java -Djava.library.path=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/jri -cp .:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/jri/JRI.jar SimpleR
  *BEGIN*
Forecast: 0
Result: 14436.670778092368
Forecast: 1
Result: 14104.789779948998
Forecast: 2
Result: 14104.789779948998
Forecast: 3
Result: 14104.789779948998
Forecast: 4
Result: 14104.789779948998
  *DONE*
```

I am getting proper output. My SimpleR.java looks like:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.*;

public class SimpleR {

  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"},false,null);
    System.out.println("  *BEGIN*  ");
    // enable R log
    rengine.eval("log<-file('/tmp/file.log')");
    rengine.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE)");
    rengine.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE, type='message')");
    rengine.eval("library(forecast)");
    double[] trainingData =  {10930,10318,10595,10972,7706,6756,9092,10551,9722,10913,11151,8186,6422,
            + 6337,11649,11652,10310,12043,7937,6476,9662,9570,9981,9331,9449,6773,6304,9355,10477,
            + 10148,10395,11261,8713,7299,10424,10795,11069,11602,11427,9095,7707,10767,12136,12812,
            + 12006,12528,10329,7818,11719,11683,12603,11495,13670,11337,10232,13261,13230,15535,
            + 16837,19598,14823,11622,19391,18177,19994,14723,15694,13248,9543,12872,13101,15053,
            + 12619,13749,10228,9725,14729,12518,14564,15085,14722,11999,9390,13481,14795,15845,
            + 15271,14686,11054,10395,14775,14618,16029,15231,14246,12095,10473,15323,15381,14947};
    rengine.assign("value", trainingData);
    rengine.eval("traindatats<-ts(value)");
    rengine.eval("ar<-auto.arima(traindatats)");
    REXP result = rengine.eval("f<-predict(ar,n.ahead=" + 5 + ")");
    if(result == null) {
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
    double forecast[] = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
      System.out.println("Forecast: " + i);
      forecast[i] = rengine.eval("f$pred[" + (i+1) + "]").asDouble();
      System.out.println("Result: " + forecast[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("  *DONE*  ");
  }
}
```

It seems to be working fine.

By logging I am referring to code:

```
rengine.eval("log<-file('/tmp/file.log')");
rengine.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE)");
rengine.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE, type='message')");
```

Comment: But, if the following code directly run on R, there is no any problem. 

`value <- data`
`traindatats<-ts(value)`
`ar<-auto.arima(traindatats)`
`f<-predict(ar,n.ahead=5)`
`for (i in 1:5){`
  `print(f$pred[i])`
`}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But The SimpleR.java doesn't work for me. The result is
`  *BEGIN*`  
`Error`
`Forecast: 0`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`
` at SimpleR.main(SimpleR.java:26)`

Comment: I found an abnormal thing. In JAVA, when I call arima(), it runs for a few seconds. Then, it generates the output correctly. However, when I call auto.arima() in JAVA, it runs very quickly. Then, it outputs the error message.

Comment: Try to use log (take a look at source code). This way, you will be able to see what happens on R side ;)

Comment: I am following your suggestion. I guess JRI isn't configured correctly though I can call arima() R funcation in JAVA.

Comment: What happens if you enable logging? Do you get any errors inside /tmp/file.log?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After checking out the log file, it seems not to show any activity related to auto.arima() function. Besides, when I try to call ndiffs() in JAVA, it doesn't work either. Because I also tried to use another computer to run auto.arima() in JAVA. The error message is the same. So, I changed to use `RServe' to call R functions in JAVA. Fortunately, everything is good with RServe. I guess that I do not set up system environments correctly, although I can run arima() in JAVA.